# How to properly import neighboring package into current package in python?

Tags: python, module, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I know there are a million similar questions and articles describing how to define and mange packages in general, but the following does not seem to work and I have run out of things to try. Im hoping I'm just missing something completely obvious to someone else.

This is my current project structure:

```
root-folder/
  |- app/
      |- cube/
          |- algorithms/
              |- __init__.py
              |- utils.py
              |- ...
          |- models/
              |- __init__.py
              |- cube.py
              |- ...
          |- __init__.py
          |- main.py
          |- README.md
      |- presentation/
          |- cli_test/
              |- __init__.py
              |- run.py
          |- unity/
              |- __init__.py
              |- producer.py
          |- __init__.py
          |- README.md
      |- __init__.py
```

Im trying to import afunction from `main.py` in app.cube into `producer.py` in app.presentation.unity as follows:

```
from app.cube.main import run
```

but when I try to run the producer file it gives me the following:

```
$ python app/presentation/unity/producer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/presentation/unity/producer.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.cube.main import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

I tried moving files around, renaming folders, adding and removing `__init__.py` files, but I always get a similar issue. In the current setup all of the init files are empty btw.

Another thing to note is that the `cube` folder used to be at the root level of the project before I added the `presentation` folder, and I was able to import functions and classes both ways between the `models` and `algorithms` modules and also import stuff from the `cube` module into the root level. The contents of the `cube` folder have not changed since. It's like adding an extra layer is not meant to work or something which sounds dumb.

For some final info, Im using Python 3.8.5 installed through pyenv 2.2.0 on MacOs Catalina(10.15.6)

---

## Solution!

As proposed in the first comment of this post, running it as follows allows you to run a "library module as a script", and it works for me now!

```
python -m app.presentation.unity.producer
```

Comment: You should call `python -m app.presentation.unity.producer` in order to run the "library module as a script" according to the command-line help of the Python interpreter.

Comment: John, this worked beautifully! I didn't even know I could run stuff like this. Thanks a ton and a half!

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(1, '/root-folder/app/cube') 
from main import run
```

Comment: Right, I have not tried path manipulation because I feel there should be a way to get this working without any hacky fixes.